# Disable submission for hidden fileds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with hidden select drop downs that are dynamically shown based on user selection. When the form is submitted, all form fields including the hidden ones are posting to the PHP script.
The form is submitted using ajax. Is there a way to disable hidden fields submissions.
Thank you.

The Ajax:

```
$("#new-contact-form").validate({
            rules: {
                contact_fname: "required",
                contact_lname: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                contact_fname: "First name is missing",
                contact_lname: "Last name is missing",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              $.ajax ({
                type:"POST",
                url:"../includes/functions/contact-functions.php",
                data: $('form#new-contact-form').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                  closeModal();
                  //notify();
                  location.reload();

                },
              });
            }
        });
```

The modal / form partial only (very long form):

```
 <div class="form-group ">
      <label  class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Type</label>
     <div class="col-lg-4">
        <select class="form-control m-bot15" id="contact_type">
            <option value="None"> Contact Type</option>
            <option value="Account">Account</option>
            <option Value="Service_provider">Service Provider</option>
            <option value="Lead">Lead</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!--Start Contact Type inputs-->                                                
          <!-- Show Accounts -->
     <div class="col-lg-5 ">
        <select class="form-control m-bot15 " id="accounts_list" name="contact_account_name" style="display:none">
            <option value="no-account">Select Account</option>
            <?php list_accounts();?>
            <option value="Other_Account">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>                                                
      <!--Show Service Providers-->
     <div class="col-lg-5 ">
            <select class="form-control m-bot15 " id="providers_list" name="contact_sp_name" style="display:none">
            <option value="no-sp">Select Service Provider</option>
                <?php list_providers();?>
                <option value="Other_Provider">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>      
    </div>
```

The functions:

```
if ($_POST['contact_account_name']!='Other_Account' && $_POST['contact_account_name'] != 'no-account' && $_POST['contact_sp_name'] = 'no-sp') {

        $current_account_id = $_POST['contact_account_name'];
        $result = "INSERT INTO contacts (contact_fname, contact_lname, contact_email, contact_phone, contact_fax, contact_account_id, contact_type)
        VALUES ('$contact_fname', '$contact_lname', '$contact_email', '$contact_phone', '$contact_fax', '$current_account_id', 1)";

        mysqli_query($connection, $result);
        if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
         exit();
                }
                echo "new ct insert";
        }

        //insert contact with new account
        elseif ($_POST['contact_account_name'] ='Other_Account' && $_POST['contact_sp_name'] = 'no-sp' ){
                $new_account_name = $_POST['new_account_name'];
                $new_account = "INSERT INTO accounts (account_name, account_address1, account_address2, account_city, account_state, account_zip, account_phone)
        VALUES ('$new_account_name', '$contact_address1', '$contact_address2', '$contact_city', '$contact_state', '$contact_zip', '$contact_phone')";

        mysqli_query($connection, $new_account);
        if (!$new_account) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
         exit();
                }
                echo "new acct insert";

                $new_account_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

                $result = "INSERT INTO contacts (contact_fname, contact_lname, contact_email, contact_phone, contact_fax, contact_account_id, contact_type)
                VALUES ('$contact_fname', '$contact_lname', '$contact_email', '$contact_phone', '$contact_fax', '$new_account_inserted_id', 1)";

                mysqli_query($connection, $result);
                if (!$result) {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
                 exit();
                        }
                                        echo "new ct with act insert";

        }

        //insert contact with existing SP
        elseif ($_POST['contact_sp_name']!='Other_Account'  && $_POST['contact_account_name'] = 'no-account') {

        $current_sp_id = $_POST['contact_sp_name'];
        $result = "INSERT INTO contacts (contact_fname, contact_lname, contact_email, contact_phone, contact_fax, contact_account_id, contact_type)
        VALUES ('$contact_fname', '$contact_lname', '$contact_email', '$contact_phone', '$contact_fax', '$current_sp_id', 2)";

        mysqli_query($connection, $result);
        if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
         exit();
                }
                                echo "new sp insert";

        }
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Scriptable i added parts of the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you are already using JavaScript to dynamically change the 'style:display' value, you could instead place a <div> for each section you want hidden and leave the HTML empty, then set the element.innerHTML as needed.

Comment: Serialising the form would get all values of the form, you should add some checking at the start of your PHP code to see if the select values fields are set to default value or not. If they are not then you know that select field has been selected and is usable. You should always try to build your backend code so that it could work without JS validation

Comment: Set the property `disabled="disabled"` on any hidden element and when you show the hidden fields also set `$(element).prop('disabled', false);`. Or write your own serialize function that skips hidden fields.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thank you , i will try the disabled function.

Answer (score 0):

I could see something like this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {

    var $fields = $('#myForm :input');

    $fields.each(function() {

        if( $(this).val() == "") {

             $(this).remove(); 
        }
    });

    // submit remaining forms data
});
```